# Monitoring output of parallel subprocess in python 2.7 - pocketsphinx

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing

I'm new to python and maybe my problem might be rather obvious and simple.

My goal would be to run a pocketsphinx_continuous in parallel with my own program. And when needed I would like to poll for output created by pocketsphinx.

I found different questions and answers related to parallel processing etc in python. But I need to keep sub-process running until my own program is running.

I'm using following command:

```
command ='pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm ~/speech/et/models/hmm/est16k.cd_ptm_1000-mapadapt -jsgf ~/speech/et/models/lm/robot2.jsgf -dict ~/speech/et/robot.dict 2>/dev/null | grep "^000"'
```

Output of pocketsphinx will be something like:

0000001:some text; 
0000002: some more text.

Any references or hints are most welcome!

Thank you!

Edit:

Thanks for your response but i solve it as following:

```
def start(self):
       print "start"
       command ='pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm ~/speech/et/models/hmm/est16k.cd_ptm_1000-mapadapt -jsgf ~/speech/et/models/lm/robot2.jsgf -dict ~/speech/et/robot.dict'
       pocketsphinx = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)  
       thread.start_new_thread(self.listen_to_pocketsphinx, (pocketsphinx,))

   def listen_to_pocketsphinx(self,pocketsphinx):
       while True:
           line = pocketsphinx.stdout.readline()
           if line.startswith("000"):
             sentence = line.partition(": ")[2].strip()
             if sentence:
                 self.direction = sentence
             else:
                 self.direction = ""
```

I'm not sure that it's the most elegant way but it worked for me.

So for me the case is closed.

Thank you!

Comment: What you need is an asynchronous I/O framework to assist with the management of multiple I/O streams and running processes. I could recommend one I'm quite biased on :)

Comment: My python program is later used by pyrobot and I'm not sure how Pyrobot will accept third party frameworks. Also i should mention that I'm using Ubuntu as OS.

I'll try to use this [Circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits)

Comment: Fortunately circuits (*whilst a 3rd-party framework*) is pure Python with no other external dependencies. It should work fine with PyRobot :)

Comment: Can you refer to some example where Circuits is used for creating new sub-process and read its output?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/circuits/circuits-dev/src/tip/examples/ping.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal recommendation is that you use an **Asynchronous Application Framework**. There are many out there with varying features and levels of simplicity and complexity.

I have a personal bias towards [circuits](http://circuitsframework.com/) and very generically you would implement something like this (*using circuits-dev from https://bitbucket.org/circuits/circuits-dev*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import sys


from circuits import Component
from circuits.io import stdout, Process, write


class Ping(Component):

    stdout = stdout

    def init(self, host):
        self.p = Process(["/bin/ping", host]).register(self)
        self.p.start()

    def read(self, data):
        self.fire(write(data), stdout)


app = Ping(sys.argv[1])
app.run()
```

Something like this could also be running a simple web server for example:

```
from circuits.web import Controller, Server

class Root(Controller):

    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

Server(("0.0.0.0", 8000)).register(app)
```